# Add a char to a char* in C without library functions, arrays, or memory management

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible add a `char` to a `char *` in C without library functions, arrays, or memory management?

I need to do it without creating any arrays, so I can't use anything with `[]`. I can't use `malloc` or anything of the sort, and I can't use library functions.

My real goal is to rotate a string.

Is there any way to concat strings with the `+` operator in C like you could in Java?

Here's what I have:

```
char* alphabet = "abcdefghijklmop"
//I want to create a new string which is the rotated version of that string by
// n amount so if n was 3 it would be "defghijklmnopabc"

char* = string;

for(i=0; i<lengthOfString; i++){
        int amountToShiftBy = (n+i);
        if(amountToShiftBy>=lengthOfString)
                amountToShiftBy-=lengthOfString;
        string = string + *(alphabet+shift); //obviously doesn't work
}
```

Comment: You can't have a pointer without memory to point at...

Comment: I have memory I just meant I cant use function like malloc, realloc, calloc, mmap,

Comment: @ChrisDodd - Well... In C you definitely can.

Comment: you need char arrays to make strings

Comment: No, the + operator is the addition operator it's silly to use it for string concatenation, c++ does that too. Please post the code you have so far, I mean, show me the two strings you are willing to concatenate, how are they defined if they are not arrays and you cannot use `malloc()`?.

Comment: You're working with an array of characters regardless.  So, maybe you can't use subscripts — which is a moderately pointless prohibition, but probably what you really mean by 'no arrays'.  You simply can't avoid working with an array of characters if you're working with strings, whether rotating or adding to the end.  And no, there are no string manipulation operators in C — it is a lower level language than Java.  Things like `+` simply don't work in C as a string concatenation operator.  At the operator level, C doesn't really have strings at all.

Comment: I added the code I'm working with. By no arrays I meant I can't do something like char alphabet[]. As in I can't use the brackets.

Comment: Note that you can't modify a string literal reliably.  On most systems, your code will crash as soon as you try to write to it.  You must have an array with which to work.

Comment: Can't have a string without an array? `char c = '\0'; size_t length_of_c = strlen(&c);` What is this, @JonathanLeffler?

Comment: A degenerate case which you could not extend.  It is equivalent to a one-element array

Comment: If you are restricted from using memory management routines and arrays then are you allowed to use a struct with N number of char fields? If so, then you could use the struct for your string manipulation by setting a pointer to the struct ( ie address of the struct) and use that for your string buffer.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise, your question is ill-defined, what you probably mean is silly and a waste of time but nonetheless possible.

> Is it possible to do what is in the title?
>
> Add a `char` to a `char*` ...

Sure, but once you learn C properly (e.g. by reading from a book such as K&R2E, and doing the exercises as you come across them rather than bypassing them) you'll learn that this probably isn't what you want to accomplish.

As an example, if you have a `char c;` and you write `&c + 42`, you've added 42 to the pointer to c, which advances that pointer forty-two characters beyond the start of `c`; obviously this is an error, because `c` only has room for *one* character.

> ... without library functions, arrays, or, memory managem[e]nt".

Sure. See the example above.

In the real world, this would be a stupid exercise. We're taught to reuse library functions because it's quicker to reuse existing code than to reinvent the wheel, test/debug the reinvention, fine-tune the invention and then test/debug it again.

It's highly likely that the standard library developers know how to write more optimal code per-platform than you do.

> ... need to do it without creating any arrays, so I can't use anything with []...

Technically, the `[]` subscript operator *isn't* an array operator; it's a pointer operator (just like the unary `*` operator you used in your code), as [6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) of the C standard explains:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

---

> Is there any way to concat strings with the + operator in C ...

There's [a variation of the xor swap, known as the add swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Variations) which *could* be used for concatenation. However, as I explained earlier in this post, if this is more efficient then your standard library devs would've used it. Additionally, it certainly wouldn't be a *succinct*, *idiomatic* or *elegant* solution; it'd be the equivalent to someone throwing up in a dirty toilet and calling it nutritious soup. You're better off coming up with a simpler approach.

```
void append_char(char *str, char c) {
    str += strlen(str);
    *str++ = c;  // This could be written using an add swap
    *str = '\0'; // ... and so could this
}
```

Not allowed to use `strlen` from `<string.h>`? Simple solution: Open up the source code for the standard library, find the `strlen` code, copy and paste it into your program and... *throw your computer in the bin!* Your professor is teaching you to waste time.

If your professor had instructed you to rewrite the standard library to spec, however, this would be a useful exercise as it'd teach you how to use the standard library.

> ... like you could in java?

If you want to use Java features, then use Java. C isn't Java. Things are done differently.

This whole `<string.h>` thing may seem counter-intuitive, however from learning numerous languages myself (*including* both Java and C) I can tell you there are pros and cons to just about every language. Java has *many* cons. So does C, though if you give it a chance you'll find C has *far* fewer.

FWIW, I'm not a C fanboy. I'm a Haskell fanboy. Haskell is semantically closer to Java, as it has garbage collection, static types and numerous forms of polymorphism.

> ```
> char* alphabet = "abcdefghijklmop"
> //I want to create a new string which is the rotated version of that string by n amount so if n was 3 it would be "defghijklmnopabc"
> ```

Your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) doesn't compile (it fails the **C** in the acronym MCVE) and uses an array (it fails the test in the title).

Nonetheless, this goal is also possible. Create a new array, the same size as the string you're modifying, copy the tail of the source in as the head of the destination and the head of the source in as the tail of the destination. For example:

```
void rotate_string(char *destination, char const *source, size_t n) {
    if (n > strlen(n) || n > INT_MAX) { n = 0; }
    sprintf(destination, "%s%.*s", source + n, (int) n, source);
}
```

If you're not allowed to reuse `sprintf` from the standard library, don't include the standard library; just reinvent `sprintf`. That's part of the exercise, right?

If you're not allowed to use `INT_MAX` from the standard library, use `32767` or `42` in it's place; it's a magic number, and we're commonly taught *not* to use magic numbers... but your exercise is teaching you to do exactly that. Oh well. Quality of education matters; I'll be making noise if my professor tries this on me!